# Is the compound-requirement syntax just syntactic sugar for a simple-requirement followed by a nested-requirement?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

[[expr.prim.req.compound]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:compound-requirement) contains an example:

> [*Example [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#req.compound-example-1)*: Given concepts C and D,
>
> ```cpp
> requires {
>   { E1 } -> C;
>   { E2 } -> D<A1, …, An>;
> };
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```cpp
> requires {
>   E1; requires C<decltype((E1))>;
>   E2; requires D<decltype((E2)), A1, …, An>;
> };
> ```
>
> (including in the case where *n* is zero). — *end example*]

However, since that example is not aligned with [the paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#req.compound-1) but [a nested list item](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#req.compound-1.3.2), I'm asking confirmation here.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue here. The example is part of that particular list item because that particular list item is the one that actually explains how to interpret the *return-type-requirement*.

Comment: The text you're quoting very clearly answers your question you're question, no?

Comment: @Barry, yes, it does but.. I mean, the example to me looks like an example about the _compound-requirement_ as a whole, but it is aligned with just the 1.3.2 point, so I thought I'm maybe misunderstanding a bit. Also because I don't understand what 1.3.1 and 1.3.2 are saying, actually :D